# How to delete multiple checkboxes when selected in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am so much confused and messed up on how should i delete selected checkboxes at once. can anyone please help on this? I have tried many delete codes and commented it since messed up in failure. so please suggest!!!!
     The below code is written for "DELETE ALL" Button!

```
/*if(isset($_POST['delete']))
        {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM dealer_tbl");
        }
```

Some Trails on "DELETE SELECT" Button

```
if($_REQUEST['Delete'] != '')
        {
            if(!empty($_REQUEST['checkboxstatus'])) {
            $checked_values = $_REQUEST['checkboxstatus'];
            foreach($checked_values as $val) {
                $sqldel = "DELETE from dealer_tbl WHERE id = '$val'";
               mysql_query($sqldel);

            }
        }
    }
```

OR

```
 if($delete){
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM $dealer_tbl WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}*/
?>
```

Button type for DELETE ALL

```
<button type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete"  data-loading-text="Loading...">Delete All</button>
```

Button type for DELETE SELECTED

```
    <button type="submit" id="deletes" name="delete" value="delete"  data-loading-text="Loading..." onClick="delete_check.php">Delete Selected</button>
```

ANd the table goes as,

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealer_tbl");
                    while($dealer_row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                    ?>
                        <tr>

                            <td><?php echo $dealer_row['title']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dealer_row['firstname']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dealer_row['lastname']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dealer_row['email']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dealer_row['phone']; ?></td>
                            <td align="center"><a href='dealer_edit.php?did=<?=$dealer_row['uid']?>'>Edit</a> | <a href='dealer_delete.php?did=<?=$dealer_row['uid']?>'>Delete</a></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $dealer_row['uid']; ?>"  />
    </td> 
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you have pasted the whole file instead of the specific block of code.

Comment: @SumitBijvani Is this clear and fine now ? can you check and help? Thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution, [in Do it yourself mode]

1. Name you checkbox as `name="checkbox[$row[id]]"`
2. then when these checkbox got submitted, you will get an array, where Key is the ID to delete.
3. Extract Array key, implode them in comma seperate list.
4. Run SQL query `delete from table where id in (<yourimplodedkeys>)`
5. Try it yourself and live happy.

Answer (score 0):

Put the table inside of `<form>` tag , too. In this case checkboxes's parameters will receives.

Answer (score 0):

your right answer is :

```
<?php
$delete=$_POST['delete'];
$chkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
if($delete){
  for($i=0;$i<count($chkbox);$i++){
    $del_id = $chkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $dealer_tbl WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }
 ?>
```